# Substring method that return substring of the original

Tags: c++, substring

I am asked to create a `Substring()` method that returns a substring of the original string which begins at location `start` and is as long as `length`

Here is how I attempted to implement the function in my .cpp file:

```
MyString sub;

sub = new char[length];

for(int i = start; i <length; i++)
{
    sub[i] = this[i];
}

return sub;
```

and I got this error:

> error: expected unqualified-id before `[` token
>   MyString.cpp:206: error: no match for `operator[]` in `sub[i]`

Note: I am not supposed to overload [].
MyString is the defined class.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: We probably need to see the definition of `MyString` before we can provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: `this` is a pointer so try using `this->substr` instead of  `this.substr`

Comment: Do you *understand* what `MyString` is? If not, that's your starting point. We don't know what it is, you don't tell us. The errors are pretty self explanatory though (esp. if you have some good course notes or a book)

Comment: You have posted a couple of questions already, and have been suggested not to return references before. Why do you keep on returning references?

Comment: (Hint) Where do you store the characters for your string? (This is the variable you need to access, not `this`.)

Comment: I just need help on this line: sub[i] = this[i]; I cannot use the [] operator so I wanted to know what is another way to copy the substring from "this" into the new char array??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply means that this.substr() is not valid C++.
this is a pointer to the current object. So unless the method MyString::substr() exists, you can't do that.

Starting from that, I don't know which members there are in your MyString class. If there is a std::string, you can use the substr method on it. f the underlying member is just a char*, you will have to use simple array and c-string operations on it to extract a subtring from it.

With an exemple. If your class is like this

```
class MyString
{
    private:
        std::string _str;

    public:
        // Constructor
        MyString(std::string str);
        // Your method
        MyString Substring(int start, int length) const;
};
```

Then your Substring method will be like this:

```
MyString MyString::Substring(int start, int length) const
{
    return MyString(_str.substr(start, length));
}
```

On the other hand, if your class MyString is like that:

```
class MyString
{
    private:
        char* _str;

    public:
        // Constructor
        MyString(char* str);
        // Your method
        MyString Substring(int start, int length) const;
};
```

Then your method will be like this:

```
MyString MyString::Substring(int start, int length) const
{
    char* res_str = new char[length+1];
    memcpy(res_str, (char*) _str + start, length);
    res_str[length] = '\0';
    return MyString(res_str);
}
```

EDIT : If we look at the code you provided (after last edit), it seems that you are actually using an underlying char*. So let's have a look at what you wrote^^

```
MyString sub;
sub = new char[length];
```

What you want to do is actually modify the characters of the underlying char*. So what you should have done is:

```
char* sub;
sub = new char[length];
```

So instead of creating a new MyString, you will create a new char*. You can't directly assign a char* to a MyString (or at least, it's what I think). Now, let's look a the other part of your code:

```
for(int i = start; i <length; i++)
{

        sub[i] = this[i];
}
```

this is a pointer to MyString. So this[i] is equivalent to this.operator which is incalid since this is a pointer. You can't have this followed by a dot. However, if you had written this->operator, it would have searched for a function like char& MyString::operator[](int i). Since you did not defined this function, you would still have a compiler error (it's also the one you currently have for sub[i] since you defined sub as a MyString. You should write:

```
for (int i = start; i < length; i++)
{
    sub[i] = _str[i];
}
```

But it's still provided _str is a char* in your class. Then you will be able to finish your function by:

```
return MyString(sub);
```

But there, it's provided that your MyString class has a constructor that takes a char* as a parameter :)

Comment: Even if `MyString::substr()` exists, you still can't do that. He needs `this->`, not `this.` .

Comment: Yes, my first attempt was not correct at all so I have to go forward with the second attempt and I will edit my post so you can see what I've done so far.

Comment: Prefer not to use leading underscores, as they are reserved for compiler usage. Trailing underscores can be used.

Comment: If the goal of the assignment is to write a substring class, isn't it pointless to use `std::string::substring()`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yeah, I think so, but him trying to use the substr function should mean that there probably is an underlying std::string class, right?

Comment: the goal is just to return a substring of the larger string using this method.

Comment: @user1363061 Anyway, we can't give a clear answer if we don't know the class definition :/

Comment: After your edits it is clear what I have done wrong. Thank you sooo much for all of your help!