# Find method to find substring within a larger string

Tags: c++, string, find, substring

I really need help with this last part of my program. I need to find a string within a larger string and if found return the start location of the substring. From the directions:

> Note that your string location starts from 0 and ends at length -1. If the string is not found, a value of -1 will be returned.

I've started and the following code compiles, I just want to know if this is actually correct. I don't want to get in too over my head but I need some feedback from experts. Am I doing this right? Or at least am I going in the right direction?

```
const int MyString::Find(const MyString& other)
{
    int start(0);
    int counter(0);
    int end = other.Size;
    int count(0);
    int end1 = Size;
    int nfound = -1;

    char* temp;
    temp = new char[other.Size];

    if(other.String[0] != '\0' && other.String[0] != ' ')
    {
             if(other.String[count] == String[counter])
                    {
                            start = counter;

                            for(int i = count; i < end-1;i++)
                            {
                                    for(int j = counter; j < end1 -1; j++)
                                    {


                                            temp[j] = String[j];
                                    }
                            }
                            if(other == temp)
                            {
                                    return start;
                            }
                            else
                                    return nfound;
                    }

            else{
            while(other.String[count] != String[counter])
            {
                    counter++;
                    if(other.String[count] == String[counter])
                    {
                            start = counter;
                            for(int i = count; i < end-1;i++)
                            {
                                    for(int j = counter; j < end1 -1; j++)
                                    {


                                            temp[j] = String[j];
                                    }
                            }
                            if(other == temp)
                            {                 
                                    return start;                               
                            }
                            else
                                    return nfound;
                    }







            }


            }

    }
    else
    {
            return nfound;
    }





  }
```

Comment: I presume this is homework, and that's why you're not using `find`, is that right?

Comment: You are correct, this is homework and we are not allowed to use the actual find method

Comment: You should start by *describing* how your algorithm should work, then translate that into instructions and verify manually that they do what they should.

Comment: quite a few string related homework questions today

Comment: 3 whiles one in another is not close to optimal way to find sub strings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Substring method that return substring of the original](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385819/substring-method-that-return-substring-of-the-original)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is all right, though it wants a corresponding `delete` statement:

```
temp = new char[data.Size];
```

However, I doubt that this line does what you want:

```
temp = data.String;
```

Assuming that `Mystring::String` (which were more conventionally named `Mystring::string`, but let that pass) has the type `char *`, the latter line copies no characters from `data.String` into the buffer at `temp`.  Instead, *it loses the buffer,* after which `temp` is just a synonym for, and points to the selfsame memory as, `data.String`.

Comment: I presume that `temp = new char[data.Size]` is actually an error. There is no need to allocate new memory to *find* a substring within a string.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas:  No, there is no need.  You are right.  My answer however means to help the OP to discover his misconceptions so that he can eventually reach right conclusions on his own -- and this is why I have answered as I have.

Comment: I was thinking I actually needed to allocate the new memory to hold the larger string in then search through that string for the string and return the start location. Is my logic incorrect?

Comment: @user1363061:  Well, your logic is not incorrect as such, but David is right.  Beginning programmers will frequently do what you have done, which is to make unnecessary working copies of objects.  Why not just search through the characters of the *original* larger string?  Is a copy really needed to do that?

Comment: @user1363061: Is the larger string not already held in `String`?

Comment: Yes the larger string is held in String, you are right. I hadn't thought about it in that way.

Comment: @user1363061:  Do you happen to know what the `this` pointer is?  If not, we'll disregard it for now; but, if so, to what does `this` point, and what do you think it has to do with David's last point?  Also, is `Find` a member function or a nonmember function, and why does this matter?  If you can answer these two questions for yourself, it may clear some misconceptions.

Comment: From what I know, I'm sure the this pointer will point to String which holds the larger string and Find would be a member function if I'm not mistaken. It's becoming clearer, thanks for your help

Comment: @user1363061:  Let me step aside and let you continue the conversation with David, if he will.  (I must log off now in any case.  Good luck.)

Comment: No, there is nothing right about `new[]` for user code. Ever.

Answer (score 1):

When writing a piece of code, the first thing that you need is an algorithm to implement, use natural language to describe it, pen and paper to draw how the algorithm progresses, and verify that algorithm again with pen and paper. Then, once you think that you have a solution, code it and test it. But actually coding in the programming language should be the very last thing you do.

A simple algorithm to find a substring within a larger string would start by searching for the first character in the search pattern within the larger string, call that position `start`. Once found, and from that anchor compare each subsequent positions. If they don't match, then start the search for the element in the first position from `start+1`. If the comparison succeeds then you have finished. If at any point you reach the end of the original string, then the search fails:

```
// pseudocode
start <- 0
while start <> str.size()
   start <- find( str+start, pattern[0] )
   if start == str.size()
      break
   if (compare_from( str+start, pattern ) == EQUAL)
      return success(start)
if start == str.size()
   return failure
```

Now you only need to translate that into C++, it is usually a good idea to implement complex sub operations as functions, as this way you can deal with the complexity by small bites rather than try to swallow it at once. Each one of the operations above should be simple enough to implement, and then the whole algorithm will fall into place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is homework so I'm not going to give you the answer directly, but you current algorithm isn't even close to correct.

To find a sub string inside another string you'll need independent counters for the string and the sub-string.