# Function to find a string within a larger string

Tags: c++, string, oop, function

Here are the full codes that I am using to implement this program. Everything seems to compile and run, but once it runs my find method, the program seems to stop and does not execute the last line stating the matching substring within the main.cpp file. Any help is definitely appreciated!

.h file:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyString
{
    public:
            MyString();
            MyString(const char *message);
            MyString(const MyString &source);
            ~MyString();
            const void Print() const;
            const int Length() const;
            MyString& operator()(const int index, const char b);
            char& operator()(const int i);

            MyString& operator=(const MyString& rhs);
            bool operator==(const MyString& other) const;
            bool operator!=(const MyString& other) const;
            const MyString operator+(const MyString& rhs) const;
            MyString& operator+=(const MyString& rhs);
            friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const MyString& rhs);
            const int Find(const MyString& other);
            MyString Substring(int start, int length);

    private:
            char *String;
            int Size;


   };

  istream& operator>>(istream& input, MyString& rhs);
```

.cpp file:

```
   #include <iostream>
  #include <cstdlib>
  #include "MyString.h"

  using namespace std;

  //default constructor that sets the initial string to the value "Hello World"
 MyString::MyString()
 {
    char temp[] = "Hello World";

    int counter(0);
    while(temp[counter] != '\0')
    {
            counter++;
    }
    Size = counter;
    String = new char [Size];
    for(int i=0; i < Size; i++)
            String[i] = temp[i];

 }

 //alternate constructor that allows for setting of the inital value of the string
 MyString::MyString(const char *message)
{
    int counter(0);
    while(message[counter] != '\0')
    {
            counter++;
    }
    Size = counter;
    String = new char [Size];
    for(int i=0; i < Size; i++)
            String[i] = message[i];
  }

    //copy constructor
  MyString::MyString(const MyString &source)
  {

     int counter(0);
    while(source.String[counter] != '\0')
    {
            counter++;
    }
    Size = counter;
    String = new char[Size];
    for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
            String[i] = source.String[i];
  }

 //Deconstructor
 MyString::~MyString()
{
    delete [] String;
 }

//Length() method that reports the length of the string
const int MyString::Length() const
{
    int counter(0);

    while(String[counter] != '\0')
    {
            counter ++;
    }
    return (counter);
 }

/*Parenthesis operator should be overloaded to replace the Set and Get functions of    your previous assignment. Note that both instances should issue exit(1) upon violation of the string array bounaries.
*/
 MyString& MyString::operator()(const int index, const char b)
{
    if(String[index] == '\0')
    {
            exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
            String[index] = b;
    }
}

char& MyString::operator()(const int i)
{
    if(String[i] == '\0')
    {
            exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
            return String[i];
    }
}
 /*Assignment operator (=) which will copy the source string into the destination string. Note that size of the destination needs to be adjusted to be the same as the source.
 */
   MyString& MyString::operator=(const MyString& rhs)
  {
    if(this != &rhs)
    {
            delete [] String;
            String = new char[rhs.Size];
            Size = rhs.Size;

            for(int i = 0; i < rhs.Size+1 ; i++)
            {
                    String[i] = rhs.String[i];
            }
    }

    return *this;
  }
 /*Logical comparison operator (==) that returns true iff the two strings are identical in size and contents.
 */
  bool MyString::operator==(const MyString& other)const
  {
    if(other.Size == this->Size)
    {
            for(int i = 0; i < this->Size+1; i++)
            {
                    if(&other == this)                               

                        return true;
            }
    }
    else
            return false;
    }

 //Negated logical comparison operator (!=) that returns boolean negation of 2
    bool MyString::operator!=(const MyString& other) const
  {
    return !(*this == other);
  }

 //Addition operator (+) that concatenates two strings
 const MyString MyString::operator+(const MyString& rhs) const
 {
    char* tmp = new char[Size + rhs.Size +1];

    for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
            tmp[i] = String[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < rhs.Size+1; i++)
    {
            tmp[i+Size] = rhs.String[i];
    }
    MyString result;

    delete [] result.String;
    result.String = tmp;
    result.Size = Size+rhs.Size;

    return result;
 }
 /*Addition/Assigment operator (+=) used in the following fashion: String1 += String2 to operate as String1 = String1 + String2
*/
MyString& MyString::operator+=(const MyString& rhs)
{
    char* tmp = new char[Size + rhs.Size + 1];

    for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
            tmp[i] = String[i];
    }        for(int i = 0; i < rhs.Size+1; i++)
    {
            tmp[i+Size] = rhs.String[i];
    }

    delete [] String;
    String = tmp;
    Size += rhs.Size;

    return *this;
 }
 istream& operator>>(istream& input, MyString& rhs)
{
    char* t;
    int size(256);
    t = new char[size];
    input.getline(t,size);

    rhs = MyString(t);
    delete [] t;

    return input;
 }

 ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const MyString& rhs)
{
    if(rhs.String != '\0')
    {
            output << rhs.String;
    }
    else
    {
            output<<"No String to output\n";
    }

    return output;
 }

  const int MyString::Find(const MyString& other)
 {
       int nfound = -1;

    if(other.Size > Size)
    {
            return nfound;
    }
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
            for(j = 0; j < other.Size; j++)
            {
                    if( ((i+j) >= Size) || (String[i+j] != other.String[j]) )
                    {
                            break;
                    }

            }

            if(j == other.Size)
            {
                    return i;
            }

    }

    return nfound;
    }
  /*MyString::Substring(start, length). This method returns a substring of the original string that contains the same characters as the original string starting at location start and is as long as length.
 */

 MyString MyString::Substring(int start, int length)
 {
    char* sub;
    sub = new char[length+1];


    while(start != '\0')
    {
            for(int i = start; i < length+1; i++)
            {
                    sub[i] = String[i];
            }
    }
    return MyString(sub);
 }

 //Print() method that prints the string
 const void MyString::Print() const
 {

    for(int i=0; i < Size; i++)
    {
            cout<<String[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;
  }
```

main.cpp file:

```
  #include <cstdlib>
  #include <iostream>
 #include "MyString.h"


  using namespace std;

 /*
 *
 */
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{

 MyString String1; // String1 must be defined within the scope

 const MyString ConstString("Target string");          //Test of alternate constructor

  MyString SearchString;  //Test of default constructor that should set "Hello World". W/o ()
 MyString TargetString (String1); //Test of copy constructor


  cout << "Please enter two strings. ";
 cout << "Each string needs to be shorter than 256 characters or terminated by /\n." << endl;
 cout << "The first string will be searched to see whether it contains exactly the second string. " << endl;

  cin >> SearchString >> TargetString; // Test of cascaded string-extraction operator


 if(SearchString.Find(TargetString) == -1) {
      cout << TargetString << " is not in " << SearchString << endl;
   }
   else {
    cout << TargetString << " is in " << SearchString << endl;
    cout << "Details of the hit: " << endl;
    cout << "Starting poisition of the hit: " << SearchString.Find(TargetString) << endl;
    cout << "The matching substring is: " << SearchString.Substring(SearchString.Find(TargetString), TargetString.Length());
  }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fire up your debugger and step into it.

Comment: try `for(int j = 0; j < end; j++)` you don't need to subtract 1

Comment: being that this is a homework I don't/shouldn't give you the answer i can tell you this the logic behind `if(String[i] != other.String[j])` is a bit wrong or incomplete. though I could be wrong :) if you need any help let me know.

Comment: It seems that even after I  changed it, I get the same results.

Comment: @samy.vilar I do need help, I'm trying to think through with logic. What I need is to search through the first string for the second string and all I can think of is comparing the first character of the second with that of the first and continue until a match is found. If a match isn't found, return -1, but once a match is found compare the next characters in both strings until length of the second-1 is reached, then return the starting location of substring in string one. Converting this to syntax is the problem.

Comment: yes but the way youve implemented is wrong, at each index you need to compare the substring with the rest of the string but your only comparing the first char of the original string not the whole string. I wrote up the solution as an answer but this is a homework sorry, you need something like this `if(String[i + j] != other.String[j]) ` this will compare the string and the substring at different indices, but you need to check if the substring is smaller then String or else!

Comment: Think of it as a sliding window, where i represents the offset, and the window is the substring you are looking for, initially both 0, if found return index which is 0, if not increase index to 1 and search again, if the window reaches toward the end you have to becareful since it can pass the `String` thats really bad. index(i) is our offset from the base, starts at 0 gets incremented j is our offset in the window, it always start at 0 every time we increment i.

Comment: I will update my question so you can see what I did differently. I think I'm still missing something.

Comment: Your window metaphor made things rather clear, thank you for that. My only concern is what if a hit is returned but there really isn't a match such as if I searched banana for nao.

Comment: so close, take a look at my answer, let me know you have any issues, havent tested it. Im assuming that other is the substring we are searching for.

Comment: fundamentally `if(j == end)` needs to be outside the inner loop since j++ gets incremented at the end also im not sure why you are doing this `end -1` which means you are skipping the last char of the substring and like everyone else was saying j will always be less then end no matter what, whether it hit a break or not since you have `j < end - 1` so can never be `j == end` the most it will ever be is `end - 1` since `4 < 4` is false and terminates the loop.

Comment: You are correct, other is the substring we are searching for

Comment: Please excuse the -1, I didn't mean to add that.Also, if the j == end bit is outside of the loop, it gives an error stating j isn't declared in this scope.

Comment: oops I did say I didn't test it, I've updated it. sry about that.

Comment: i and j have both being declared inside the loop during initialization simply declaring them outside should suffice making sure their are both initially zero just to be safe, remember to always initialize your variables, you can take a look at my code.

Comment: Will do! Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Substring method that return substring of the original](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385819/substring-method-that-return-substring-of-the-original)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to declare i and j outside the loops.
I think you meant `j < end` and not `j < end - 1` 
I think you need to `if((i+j>=end1) || String[i+j] != other.String[j])` and not just  `if(String[i+j] != other.String[j])`

and `if(j == end)` needs to be outside the inner loop.

Here is a similar implementation.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyString
{
    private:
        string String;
        unsigned int Size;
    public:
        MyString() {
            this->String = "";
            this->Size = 0;                    
        }
        MyString(string initial_value) {
            this->String = initial_value;
            this->Size = initial_value.length();
        }        

        const int Find(const MyString& other);       
};

const int MyString::Find(const MyString& other)
{                  
    if (other.Size > Size)
        return -1; // if the substring is greater then us, there's no way we can have it as a substring
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < other.Size; j++)  
            if ( ((i + j) >= Size) || (String[i + j] != other.String[j]) ) // if they don't match, offset exceeded Size, break
                break ;
        if (j == other.Size) // We went through the entire substring, didn't hit break so j == Other.size
            return i; // return index
    }

    return -1; // if we never return anything means, we didn't find it, so return -1
}

int main()
{
    string temp1, temp2;
    getline(std::cin, temp1, '\n');
    getline(std::cin, temp2, '\n');
    MyString main_string(temp1), sub_string(temp2);

    cout << main_string.Find(sub_string) << endl;
    return 0;
}


MyString MyString::Substring(int start, int length)
{
    char* sub = new char[length + 2]; // 2 byte buffer to be safe

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)           
        sub[i] = String[start + i]; 
    sub[i] = '\0'; // always null terminated to be safe!           

    return MyString(sub);
 }
```

if theres any bugs or issues, I apologize, haven't tested it.

Comment: One issue that I did see with this implementation is the program actually stops and I have to control C to abort it once this function runs. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Do you mean the program doesnt stop? Did u properly initialize your variables? Such as Size

Comment: right! It doesn't stop. Size is defined as a private int within the class. I'm so confused on what it could possibly be, that keeps the program from ending.

Comment: sorry about that typo ... Since I don't know how you've implemented your calss this is just something I came up on the fly to test the function which works as expected.

Comment: Yes, it definitely works which is why I am so baffled as to why the program stopped. If I post my entire code, would you be able to look at it and tell me where I went wrong. Everything compiles and runs, it's just this one issue. I'm begging you, pretty please???

Comment: I know it is something so simple that I am overlooking but I've been working on this entire program for days and this particular function has taken the longest time. I really just want to figure it out and be done with it, so that I may turn it in. Please help.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will post it here momentarily.

Comment: Also please don't use cin with string, since it will stop as soon as it hits the space which is somewhat dangerous, updated the test so just type the main string [enter] followed by the substring [enter] and it will print the offset.

Comment: The only thing with that is, I am not allowed to actually use string/ #include <string> anywhere in the program, which makes this beyond difficult.

Comment: `Substring` wasn't properly implemented `while start != '\0'` doesn't make any sense start is index or offset.

Comment: But to be honest this code, needs a lot of work! so much so I don't know where to even begin, Im getting, when the application terminates,` malloc: *** error for object 0x100100080: pointer being freed was not allocated` this is quite serious, on MAC OS X using g++ 4.2. the first thing you need to fix is your copy Constructor its really <b>dangerous</b> I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: the first thing you need to fix is your copy Constructor its really dangerous, you have objects pointing to the same allocated byte array!, if the other object is destroyed it deallocates the array while the other object or objects are still pointing to it which could explain why MAC OS X Is freaking out, good luck ...

Comment: @user1363061 Did you get it working, btw I can recommend some great books on C++ if youre interested.

Comment: I didn't get it working, I am trying to go through it now. I am totally freaked out because it is due today and for it to crashing and being so dangerous, I don't know if I will be able to fix everything because from what it sounds like, it's serious errors. I can't have any memory leaks. My whole career depends on this, so I do not know what to do.

Comment: I have updated the copy constructor, hopefully this is better.

Comment: @user1363061 I highly doubt your whole career depends on a single assignment, that would be somewhat unfair, my first cpp book was http://www.amazon.com/Starting-Out-Early-Objects-Edition/dp/0136077749, simple, funny and quite brilliant, http://www.amazon.com/Software-Engineering-Approach-Shtern-Paperback/dp/B008AUKMXC/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1339763239&sr=1-1&keywords=core+c%2B%2B+2000 is a lot bigger with more software engineering techniches quite good even though is quite old relatively speaking

Comment: @user1363061  http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Specific-Improve-Programs-Designs/dp/0321334876/ref=sr_1_5?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1339763311&sr=1-5&keywords=C%2B%2B+stl explains a lot of the gotchas that cpp has which is quite few, which is y it's being the most painful,  c is far more transparent, I'm somewhat torn between having cpp be a first language I think ppl should learn c then cpp, cpp is simply to large and ur left asking why they did certaing things, mainly due to the fact that they wanted backwards compability with C, and far to many features, it requires a high degree of discipline.

Comment: @user1363061 check out python when you get a chance, good luck :) oh and the copy constructor looks better though you have to assume they give you a good string ie null terminated or else!

Comment: @user1363061 one final advise the most common functions I use from string.h  are memset, memcpy, memcmp, check them out, maybe we you want to implement them yourself as helper functions, and when you copy strings please make sure you copy the '\0' as well ...

Comment: I totally agree with what you said about cpp! Some things I just do, because I was told to, not knowing exactly why we have to do it. This assignment actually decides whether or not I continue my degree program, its a big deal.

Comment: thank you for the book suggestions, I will certainly look into those!

Comment: @user1363061 Wow that's pretty brutal, in which program are you in? The only thing that resembles this is our Phd program where we take the qualifying exam at the end of our first year, but this exam is quite hard.

Comment: yes, it is! It's for a Bachelor in Comp Sci. I just want to get over this hump and pursue what I love. I've literally stayed up nights and days working on this.

Comment: @user1363061 meant to ask which school?, also CS is both practical (programming) + theotical (discrete math,proofs) some are better at one then the other few are quite good at both, diff schools emphasize diff parts, mine tends to be more theotical with virtually all my profs having PhDs in math, I finished my BS last year, and I will be finishing MS by the end of the year haven't decided for a phd but it looks it may not be worth it, btw please use a source control either git/hg their quite crucial.

Answer (score 3):

It appears the inner loop's invariant is that j is between 0 and end-2 inclusive.  Hence j will NEVER equal end (the "matching" condition).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a problem with your `found` logic.

Your for loop is defined as `for(int j = 0; j < end -1; j++)`

but then you test for `if(j == end)`

`j` can never be equal to `end` in this for loop. Consider what you're actually trying to test for in your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Along with what everyone else said, in your Substring method you have the following bit of code:

```
 while(start != '\0')
 {
     for(int i = start; i < length+1; i++)
     {
         sub[i] = String[i];
     }
}
```

Take a moment to go over the logic of the while loop and ask yourself "what am I trying to achieve here, and what does this code *actually* do?"

Comment: I've already fixed that code and erased the while loop, I already know what it does. The only problem I am having now is the substring doesn't actually print so there is still something wrong. The output looks like this: "The matching substring is: ðäZ" any thoughts on that?

Comment: You do not NULL-terminate 'sub' and you use it to construct a MyString using a constructor that scans the input for a terminating NULL.

Comment: I'm so confused, sorry I am a beginner. Are you saying that I have to add a check for NULL after sub[i] = String[i]? and is return Mystring(sub) incorrect?

Comment: I am saying that you need a sub[i] = 0; **after** the loop finishes, to null-terminate the string.