# Returning a substring using c++ within a class

Tags: c++, string, oop, error-handling, substring

SO I have a substring function that takes in the start location of the substring and its length. With that it should extract the characters within and return them as a string, without actually using any string function.

```
//default constructor that sets the initial string to the value "Hello World"
MyString::MyString()
{
    char temp[] = "Hello World";

    int counter(0);
    while(temp[counter] != '\0')
    {
            counter++;
    }
    Size = counter;
    String = new char [Size];
    for(int i=0; i < Size; i++)
            String[i] = temp[i];
 }

  //copy constructor
  MyString::MyString(const MyString &source)
 {

    int counter(0);
    while(source.String[counter] != '\0')
    {
            counter++;
    }
    Size = counter;
    String = new char[Size];
    for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
            String[i] = source.String[i];

 }
```

Here is my substring function:

```
MyString MyString::Substring(int start, int length)
{
 char* leo = new char[length+1];
    for(int i = start; i < start + length+ 1; ++i)
    {
            leo[i-start] = String[i];
    }

    MyString sub;
    delete [] sub.String;
    sub.String = leo;
    sub.Size = length+1;
    return sub;

}
```

With this code from the main.cpp file:

```
  int main (int argc, char **argv)
 {
   MyString String1; // String1 must be defined within the scope

  const MyString ConstString("Target string");      //Test of alternate constructor 

 MyString SearchString;  //Test of default constructor that should set "Hello World". 

  MyString TargetString (String1); //Test of copy constructor


 cout << "Please enter two strings. ";

 cout << "Each string needs to be shorter than 256 characters or terminated by /\n." << endl;

 cout << "The first string will be searched to see whether it contains exactly the second string. " << endl;

cin >> SearchString >> TargetString; // Test of cascaded string-extraction operator


  if(SearchString.Find(TargetString) == -1) {

   cout << TargetString << " is not in " << SearchString << endl;
  }

   else {

   cout << TargetString << " is in " << SearchString << endl;

    cout << "Details of the hit: " << endl;

    cout << "Starting position of the hit: " << SearchString.Find(TargetString) << endl;

    cout << "The matching substring is: " << SearchString.Substring(SearchString.Find(TargetString), TargetString.Length()-1)<<"\n";
  }
```

It returns:

Please enter two strings. Each string needs to be shorter than 256 characters or terminated by /
.
The first string will be searched to see whether it contains exactly the second string.

forever

more

morev World is not in forever

Any thoughts on why it actually isn't outputting the words from user input without the extra characters? I'm lost.

Comment: What is `String[i]` in the code? Are you calling `operator []` on `this`?

Comment: Tried a debugger? Do `SearchString` and `TargetString` have the contents you expect?  Do `Find` and `Length` return the values you expect?

Comment: @mlt String is the String in the class, so I'm guessing you are right.

Comment: @aschepler SearchString and TargetString are both string given through user input and both Find and Length return the correct value

Comment: You should be `delete[]`ing `sub` somewhere too.

Comment: this is true and I'm wondering where exactly would that have to go because if I delete before I return, it wouldn't return anything.Right?

Comment: @user1363061, I'd start off with `MyString sub` in the first place. It should clean up after itself. Reuse what you have.

Comment: This is true. I hadn't thought about that either, I will work on that and edit the question momentarily.

Comment: So I did switch my code over and it works!! Thank you! I only have one other problem which deals with a copy constructor

Comment: @chris I have edited the question with more code, if you can help me please that would be awesome!

Comment: @user1363061, You still have the `start + length + 1` in there. The `+ 1` is causing the off-by-one. Also, your `sub.Size` should be `length` if it's like most of the other strings I've seen where it's a count of the number of characters, not including the null.

Comment: you're correct I've made those changes. I believe I was doing trial and error and forgot to actually take the +1 off. Any ideas on this code where the copied string isn't deleted when trying to print the user input?

Comment: @user1363061, You don't have a null terminator on the end of your copied string. The simplest way, since you find it in the original, is to use `i <= Size` so it copies the null as well.

Comment: This is to my copy constructor correct? Hmm after changing it, I get the same output. I am totally at a lost with this one

Comment: @user1363061, I just noticed your `Size = counter` doesn't include the null. You'll need an array one larger than that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Substring method that return substring of the original](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385819/substring-method-that-return-substring-of-the-original)

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = start; i < length+1; i++)
```

This isn't working the way you want it to. It should be:

```
for (int i = start; i < start + length; ++i)
```

You have an off-by-one error, and your ending condition makes no sense once you realize what it's saying.

Take a substring starting at index 2, with length 5. The characters to be copied are at indices 2 to 6, which fits the condition.

Inside, though, you have another problem. Unless `i` starts at 0, you're not copying into the proper array indices. It should be:

```
sub [i - start] = String [i];
```

That way you'll start filling `sub` at index 0.

Also, once you're done, you need to null-terminate it:

```
sub [length] = '\0';
```

That way it won't run past the end.

Comment: Actually, that makes it add a character in the substring that isn't needed. For example, I just tried searching find for in and it returned that the substring was ind instead of just in. I am still off by 1 somewhere.

Comment: @user1363061, It's working fine for me. Are you sure you put in the end condition correctly?

Comment: I believe I did. It only does that when the length is 2.

Comment: @user1363061, 2 works well for me. I think you should post the code in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using the [`std::copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) algorithm:

```
MyString MyString::Substring(int start, int length)
{
    char* sub;
    sub = new char[length + 1];
    sub[length] = '\0';

    std::copy(String + start, String + start + length, sub);
    return MyString(sub);
}
```

(I am assuming that `String` is some `char *` data member of `MyString` objects.)

Comment: I kind of assumed `std::copy` fell into the same category as "string functions".

Answer (score 0):

```
MyString MyString::Substring(int start, int length)
{
    char* sub;
    sub = new char[length+1];
    sub[length] = '\0';
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = start; i < start + length; ++i)
    {
        sub[j] = String[i];
        ++j;
    }
    return MyString(sub);
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: THANK YOU So MUCH! This worked but it is giving me and extra character at the end of the substring. I guess I am off by one somewhere?

Comment: Example: I just input target as the string searched and tar as the substring to be found and it returned: The matching substring is target=. When really it should just be tar.